# Gegenteil von „zudecken“

Tags: single-word-request

„Zudecken“ ist das Standardwort für „jemanden mit der Bettdecke bedecken und den Kopf draußen lassen“.

> Ich decke mein Kind zu.

Aber was ist das Gegenteil? „Aufdecken“ und „abdecken“ würden für mein Sprachgefühl in diesem Satz nicht funktionieren. Gibt es eine Möglichkeit zu sagen, dass man die Decke wegnimmt, weil dem Kind zu warm ist?

Comment: Wiktionary zu "aufdecken": eine Decke *zurückschlagen*

Comment: @Em1... als intransitiver Satz vielleicht, aber im Satz?! Kann ich mir nicht vorstellen.

Comment: Please be serious, @CarstenSchultz. While entdecken does not fit here, I have no such qualms with both _aufdecken_ and _abdecken_. "Ich decke mein Kind zu, da es sich abgedeckt hat", e.g. works fine for me.

Comment: Von allen Antworten die beste ist der Kommentar oben von Em1.

Comment: _Mein Kind legt sich ins Bett, ich decke es zu. … Ich **wecke** mein Kind, es steht auf._ ;) Es gibt einen deutlich geringeren pragmatischen Bedarf für eine Formulierung des Deckezurückschiebens/-ziehens, deswegen gibt es dafür auch keine konventionelle Formulierung.

Answer (score 7):

Hier passt die erste der verschiedenen im *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* (5. Aufl. Mannheim 2003) genannten Bedeutungen von „aufdecken“:

> **aufdecken**:
>
> **1.** *die Decke o. Ä. von etw., jmdm. ab-, herunternehmen:* das Kind, den Kranken, den zugedeckten Käfig a.; das Bett a. *(die Bettdecke zurückschlagen);* du hast dich im Schlaf aufgedeckt *(hast deine Bettdecke weggeschoben).*
>
> (…)

Das Wort „abdecken“ kann in diesem Zusammenhang allerdings auch verwendet werden:

> **abdecken**:
>
> **1. a)** *(etw. Bedeckendes) von etw. weg-, herunternehmen:* die Bettdecke, das Tuch von dem Krug a.;
>
> **b)** *von etw. Bedeckendem, darauf Befindlichem frei machen: das Bett a.; den Tisch a. (abräumen);* der Sturm hat viele Dächer abgedeckt *(die Ziegel, Teile des Daches flogen herunter).*
>
> (…)

Wenn man aber „aufdecken“ und „abdecken“ unbedingt vermeiden möchte, lassen sich sicherlich noch einige andere sinnverwandte Wörter finden, die in dem gegebenen Kontext richtig verstanden werden können, wie z. B.

> **freilegen**: *deckende Schichten von etw. entfernen u. es zugänglich machen:* Skelette f.; die Grundmauern eines römischen Hauses f.

Comment: Diese Antwort verdient sich mehr upvotes. +1 für das Bringen von Belegen anstelle von freiem Gedankenaustausch.

Comment: Abdecken würde ich vermeiden. "Abdecker" ist eine veraltete Berufsbezeichnung für jemanden der mit der Entsorgung/Verwertung von Tierkadarvern beschäftigt ist.

Comment: @GeriBroser ... ja, Belege sind schön, allerdings bräuchte ich hier Praxisbelege. Der Duden ist nur ein Vokabelsammelband.

Comment: @Emanuel Was Du _"schön"_ nennst, nenne ich die Basis jeden ernst genommen werden wollenden wissenschaftlichen Arbeitens. (Abgesehen davon, dass ich Dir bezüglich Duden tlw. zustimme.)

Comment: @Emanuel Sind das, was Dir – Dir vermutlich völlig unbekannte – Personen auf einer Internetplattform mitteilen, für Dich _„Praxisbelege“?_

Comment: @Sempie Vermeidest Du dann alle Wörter mit, eventuell auch unangenehmen, Mehrfachbedeutungen? Ich weiß nicht, warum mir dazu gerade _Wind_ als Beispiel einfällt. Ist vermutlich dem regnerischen Wetter hier geschuldet. Du kennst doch sicher auch [1984](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_%28Roman%29#Neusprech).

Comment: @GeriBroser... nein, ich habe an sowas wie ein paar findige Google oder Corpus-Suchen gedacht. Ich finde reine Duden-Antworten nicht sehr hilfreich, denn wenn ich wissen will, was der Duden dazu sagt, dann gucke ich da einfach nach. Ich frage ja hier, weil mich DUden und Wiktionary und so eben NICHT interessieren und ich wissen will, wie der Tenor so ist (nicht repräsentativ natürlich). Bei dieser Frage nehme ich zum Beispiel mit, dass die Meinungen auseinandergehen und es eine regionale Sache ist.

Comment: @Emanuel Tja, wenn Du das alles schon in Deiner Frage erwähnt hättest...

Comment: @Emanuel Ich habe Dir eine kurze Korpus-Analyse gemacht:

Für "Decke aufdecken" gibt es im Cosmas (Archiv der geschriebenen Sprache) überhaupt nur eine halbwegs relevante Fundstelle, nämlich im St. Gallner Tagblatt von 2010: "Mit seinem Wort und seinem Geist wird nun die **Decke aufgedeckt**, und die Bilanz kommt zum Vorschein." (metaphorische Bedeutung)

Für "Decke abdecken" sind zwar prinzipiell mehr Fundstellen vorhanden, diese beziehen sich aber ausschließlich auf die Decke als Plafond.

Offenbar sind beide Verben in dieser Konstruktion nicht in Verwendung.

Comment: @SebastianHenzl... mach doch 'ne Antwort draus

Comment: @GeriBroser... werde ab jetzt dazu schreiben "Bitte keine duden- und wiktionarybasierten Antworten"

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde "die Decke wegnehmen/entfernen" nehmen.

"Aufdecken" würde ich eher benutzen, wenn das Kind vorher nicht sichtbar war, und nur, wenn die Situation vorher beschrieben wurde. Als alleinstehender Satz klingt "Ich decken mein Kind auf" für mich merkwürdig.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man Wiktionary Glauben schenken darf (und das tue ich, positiv denkend, jetzt mal), besteht der Unterschied in:

> - [aufdecken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufdecken)
>     [1] ... eine Decke zurückschlagen (Bett oder ähnliches)
> - [abdecken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abdecken)
>     [1] entfernen
>
>   - [a] eine Decke ... entfernen

I.S.v.: Beim *Aufdecken* verbleibt die Decke auf dem Bett. Beim *Abdecken* wird sie von diesem entfernt.

Was auch mit [Loongs](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9551/loong) Beitrag korreliert:

> **aufdecken:** [...] du hast dich im Schlaf aufgedeckt (*hast deine Bettdecke weggeschoben*)
>
> **abdecken**: *(etw. Bedeckendes) von etw. weg-, herunternehmen:* die Bettdecke, [...]

Comment: Es geht aber nicht ums Bett, es geht ums Kind. Ich würde niemals "Ich decke das Kind ab" sagen.

Comment: Du vielleicht nicht, in der Region in der Du lebst. Ich, und alle anderen, hier schon. (Obwohl ich die auf tote Tiere bezogene Variante auch kenne. ;-)

Comment: Ja, das kann natürlich sein. Aus welcher Region kommst du denn? (Ich bin Berliner)

Comment: (1 )Woraus schließt Du in meiner Antwort, dass es (mir) ums Bett ging, nicht ums Kind? (2) Hatte ich auf dieser Seite schon erwähnt, steht auch in meinem Profil, aus dem östlichen A.

Answer (score 2):

**aufdecken**

Man kann etwas (Bestimmtes) aufdecken, d.h. offenlegen. Das impliziert aber, dass es vorher verdeckt war. Wenn das Gesicht des Kindes nicht zugedeckt ist, kann ich nicht das Kind aufdecken.

**abdecken**

Eine Person kann sich (reflexiv) *selbst* im Schlaf abdecken. Aktiv abdecken kann ich nur das Bett, was bedeutet, dass die Person, die darin geschlafen hat, bereits aufgestanden ist, und ich die Bettdecke nun z.B. zum Lüften aus dem Fenster hänge. Ansonsten bedeutet abdecken z.B., dass ich eine Plastikplane über das Bett lege, um es beim Streichen vor Farbspritzern zu schützen.

**zurückschlagen/wegziehen/usw.**

Das Problem ist, dass wir zwar regelmäßig andere Menschen *zu*decken, diese die Bettdecke aber in der Regel selbst wieder von sich entfernen. Warum? Jemanden zuzudecken ist eine Form der Zuwendung und Sorge und erzeugt im Zugedeckten ein Gefühl von Geborgenheit und Wohligkeit. Jemanden abzudecken, d.h. ihm diesen Schutz zu nehmen und ihn der Kälte auszusetzen, empfindet aber kaum jemand als angenehm. Wer das nicht glaubt, mag es mal mit seinem Partner oder seinen Kindern versuchen. Die Antwort wird schlechte Laune sein. Wir erwarten, dass wir uns dann unter der Decke hervorwagen dürfen, wenn wir dafür bereit sind.

Das bewirkt nun aber, dass wir zwar ein geläufiges Wort haben, mit dem der Vorgang des Zudeckens bezeichnet wird – zudecken eben –, dass uns Worte, die möglicherweise das Abnehmen der Bettdecke von einer Person bezeichnen könnten, unvertraut sind, da wir sie so selten gebrauchen. Bei allen möglichen Worten drängt sich deshalb immer die in der Regel vorhande alternative Bedeutung in den Vordergrund und stört die intendierte Bedeutung.

So deckt ein Pfleger im Krankenhaus vielleicht den Patienten für die Visite des Arztes oder die Waschung auf, oder ein Elternteil deckt ein in Schlaf schwitzendes Kind ab, aber in der Regel würden wir mehr den Vorgang beschreibende Verben benutzen und erklären was wir tun:

Wir schlagen die Decke zurück, wenn das Kind im Schlaf schwitzt, oder wir ziehen die Decke weg, wenn wir unseren Partner ärgern wollen.

Answer (score 2):

Aus den anderen Antworten und Kommentaren entnommen, wage ich zu behaupten, dass es keinen Begriff gibt, der in allen Teilen Deutschlands (und Österreich, Schweiz) verwendet wird. Mir sind *aufdecken* und *abdecken* in diesem Kontext äußerst fremd, wenngleich mich Duden und Co. eines besseren belehren.

Aus deiner Frage ist mir nicht ganz klar, ob es dir darum geht, die Decke vollends wegzunehmen, so dass der ganze Körper freiliegt, oder die Decke nur so weit zu entfernen, dass immer noch weite Teile des Körpers abgedeckt sind, die Wärme aber mehr/besser entweichen kann.

Ersteres kann den Wörterbüchern zur Folge durchaus durch *aufdecken* oder *abdecken* zum Ausdruck gebracht werden. Wobei ich *abdecken* so verstehe, dass die Decke gänzlich weggenommen wird, und *aufdecken* (und auch *zurückschlagen*) eher das Aufschlagen und Zurücklegen beim (oder gar nach dem) Aufstehen bezeichnet, wo die Bettdecke ans Bettende gelegt wird, so dass das Bett gelüftet werden kann.

Daraus resultierend kann man *aufdecken* und *zurückschlagen* durchaus auch verwenden, wenn man die zweite Sache ausdrücken möchte. Besser gefallen würde mir da aber der Begriff *zurückziehen*, wodurch deutlicher klar wird, dass sich immer noch weite Teile des Körpers unterhalb der Decke befinden:

> Da dem Kind warm war, habe ich die Decke etwas zurückgezogen.
>   Wenn du magst, ziehe ich deine Decke etwas zurück und wenn dir später kalt wird, ziehst du sie einfach wieder hoch.

Answer (score 0):

In diesem Kontext: Aufdecken.

Abdecken dagegen hat zwei Bedeutungen:
1) Ich decke die Möbel ab, um sie vor Farbspritzern zu schützen
2) Der Sturm hat das Dach abgedeckt.
-> Abdecken in der Bedeutung zudecken ist häufiger
(und wird nicht im Kontext Bettdecke benutzt).

Comment: "Ich decke mein Kind auf" klingt also genauso idiomatisch wie "Ich decke mein Kind zu"?

Comment: Hier im Südwesten von D. sogar reflexiv gebraucht: Ich decke mich auf. Wenn hier jemand die Decke wegnimmt, trägt er sie aus dem Raum ;-)

Comment: Au contraire. [Abdecken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abdecken) hat noch weit mehr. Eine davon: _[1] entfernen, [a] eine Decke._ So kenne ich das auch aus dem östlichen A.

Comment: Volle Zustimmung, wenn es um Sachen geht. Hier in SW-D würde allerdings  auf- nicht abdecken beim Kind benutzt. Ob da unterschwellig das Versteckspiel (Guckuck - Da!) mitschwingt? Aufdecken im Sinne von entdecken / enthüllen? Würde ich aber nicht als Behauptung aufstellen wollen.

Comment: Du sagst es! Bei Dir in _„SW-D“._ Hier ist das, wie gesagt, anders.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kann ein Kind zudecken, aber ich kann es nicht im entgegengesetzten Sinne aufdecken bzw. auf- und abdecken haben andere Bedeutungen. Man kann das nur umschreiben.

Vorschläge:

> Ich nehme die Decke weg.
>   Ich entferne die Decke
>   Ich schlage die Decke zurück
>   Ich hole mein Kind aus dem Bett

Ich sehe es so: das Kind zu Bett zu bringen und zuzudecken ist ein abendliches Ritual, das sehr verbreitet ist. Morgens hingegen weckt man die Kinder und sie stehen von alleine auf (idealerweise). Es gibt kein weit verbreitetes Ritual.

Comment: Hast du einen gängigen Vorschlag?

Comment: Warum gibt es hier einen Downvote???

Comment: @Emanuel It wasn't me... Aber ich vermute mal stark wegen der Aussage, dass "aufdecken" nicht geht.

Comment: Jetzt sind's schon 2 Downvotes.Leute, sagt was euch stört oder lasst den Downvote. Das ist nicht fair. Diese Anwtort ist nicht besser oder schlechter als alle anderen hier.

Comment: -1: _„aber ich kann es nicht im entgegengesetzten Sinne aufdecken bzw. auf- und abdecken“_ - Kann man schon. Siehe regionale Unterschiede und Belege in anderen Antworten/Kommentaren.